How to have a Go button in r shiny that can be used across multiple modules
I have a shiny app that contains 1 module.
You select something from a list and then press the Go button and what you have chosen is printed out.
I am using this module twice and as the Go button is within the module, the Go button gets printed twice and you have to press it after each selection.
The code is:
library(shiny)

# Module UI
exampleUI <- function(id, choice_list) {

  tagList(
    radioButtons(NS(id, "choice"), "Choose one:", choices = choice_list),
    actionButton(NS(id,"goButton"), "Go"),
    textOutput(NS(id, "message"))
  )
}

# Module Server
exampleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$goButton, {
      output$message <- renderText({
        input$choice
      })
    })
  })
}

# Main App
ui <- fluidPage(
  exampleUI(id = "helloGoodbye", choice_list = c("hello","goodbye")),
  exampleUI(id = "favouriteDataset", choice_list = c("iris","mpg","cars")),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  exampleServer("helloGoodbye")
  exampleServer("favouriteDataset")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

What I want to do is have just one Go button that when pressed prints the selections for both.
Any suggestions as to how to achieve this?

Either: 1 - pass the main server level Go button's value (as a reactive) to the module server instances.  Or 2 - get the Go button to set a reactive value some where (session$userData is an obvious choice and have the module server functions monitor the reactive.

The way to do it is to have an input in the server module for the go button and then put the go button outside of the modules within the UI of the main app.
library(shiny)

# Module UI
exampleUI <- function(id, choice_list) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    radioButtons(ns("choice"), "Choose one:", choices = choice_list),
    textOutput(ns("message"))
  )
}

# Module Server
exampleServer <- function(id, goButton) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # Reactive value to store the selected choice
    selected_choice <- reactiveVal()
    
    observeEvent(goButton(), {
      # Update the reactive value only when the button is clicked
      selected_choice(input$choice)
    })
    
    output$message <- renderText({
      # Return the stored choice value
      selected_choice()
    })
  })
}

# Main App
ui <- fluidPage(
  exampleUI(id = "helloGoodbye", choice_list = c("hello", "goodbye")),
  exampleUI(id = "favouriteDataset", choice_list = c("iris", "mpg", "cars")),
  actionButton("goButton", "Go")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  goButton <- reactive(input$goButton)
  
  exampleServer("helloGoodbye", goButton)
  exampleServer("favouriteDataset", goButton)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


